# How to convert string into date/time?

Tags: python, datetime

I have researched how to do this, but when I print the date and time separately there are other values that appear e.g. `00:00:00` and `1900-01-01`.

Code:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('17/12/2018', '%d/%m/%Y')
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:26:09', '%H:%M:%S')
print(date)
print(time)
```

Expected Output:

```
17/12/2018
13:26:09
>>>
```

Output:

```
2018-12-17 00:00:00
1900-01-01 13:26:09
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `datetime.date()` and `datetime.time()` functions:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('17/12/2018', '%d/%m/%Y')  # this is a datetime
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:26:09', '%H:%M:%S')    # this is also a datetime
print(date.date()) # just the date
print(time.time()) # just the time
```

Output:

```
2018-12-17   # do date.strftime('%%d/%m/%Y') to create the string representation you want
13:26:09     # default visualisation is same as you want
```

You create 2 datetime instances - one only by specifying the time, the other buy only specifying the date. The other param is supplied by default.

- see [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

---

Alternativly you can use:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('17/12/2018', '%d/%m/%Y').date()  # date object
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:26:09', '%H:%M:%S').time()    # time object
```

Comment: @Newbie101 - You can take only the `date` part from the via `datetime.datetime.strptime(...)` created date() - it will be displayers with it's default representation - which for me is `2018-12-17` - if you want your special format `17/12/2018` you need to strftime the date() object